# GSON not handlig initialized static list correctly

Tags: json, arraylist, gson

If I do this:

```
public static volatile ArrayList<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>(){
    {
        add(new Process("News Workflow", "This is the workflow for the news segment", "image"));
    }
};
```

and then this:

```
String jsonResponse = gson.toJson(processes);
```

jsonResponse is null.

But if I do this:

```
public static volatile ArrayList<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();
processes.add(new Process("nam", "description", "image"));
String jsonResponse = gson.toJson(processes);
```

Json response is:

```
[{"name":"nam","description":"description","image":"image"}]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what is the problem with Gson, but do you know, that you are creating subclass of ArrayList here?

```java
new ArrayList<Process>(){
    {
        add(new Process("News Workflow", "This is the workflow for the news segment", "image"));
    }
};
```

You can check that by

```
System.out.println( processes.getClass().getName() );
```

it won't print `java.util.ArrayList`.

I think you wanted to use static initialization as

```java
public static volatile ArrayList<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();
static {
    processes.add( new Process( "News Workflow", "This is the workflow for the news segment", "image" ) );
};
```

It seems that there is problem with anonymous classes, same problem is here

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class GSonAnonymTest {

    interface Holder {
        String get();
    }

    static Holder h = new Holder() {
        String s = "value";

        @Override
        public String get() {
            return s;
        }
    };

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        final GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
        final Gson gson = gb.create();

        System.out.println( "h:" + gson.toJson( h ) );
        System.out.println( h.get() );
    }

}
```

**UPD:** look at [Gson User Guide - Finer Points with Objects](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects), last point "...anonymous classes, and local classes are ignored and not included in serialization or deserialization..."